# How do I avoid duplicate action dispatches caused by to a delay in redux store update/propagation of redux state to connected components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React app that uses React-Router and Redux.

This app has certain routes that require authentication, in this case I'm redirecting the user to a login page as follows.

```
return <Redirect 
  to={{
    pathname: '/login',
    search: `?ret=${encodeURIComponent(location.pathname)}`
}}
```

The login page is rendered using a Login component, which is connected to the redux store and checks a boolean `isSignedIn`. When `isSignedIn === true`, I redirect the user to the path specified in the `ret` query param. The relevant code is below.

```
const Login = (props) => {
    if (!props.isSignedIn) {
        // show a message and CTA asking the user to log in
    }

    const queryParams =  qs.parse(props.location.search, { ignoreQueryPrefix: true });
    const ret = queryParams.ret || '/';
    
    return <Redirect to={ret} />
}
```

I'm using google oAuth2 in the app, and after the user signs in via Google, I dispatch a SIGN_IN action which updates `isSignedIn` to `true`. The oAuth flow is handled by a GoogleAuth component, which checks whether a user is signed in each time a page is rendered, and also handles the sign in/sign out click events. This component renders on every page of the app.

```
class GoogleAuth extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            window.gapi.client.init({
                clientId: 'someclientid',
                scope: 'email'
            }).then(() => {
                this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                // initial check to see if user is signed in
                this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
                // listens for change in google oAuth status
                this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
            })
        });
    };

    onAuthChange = async (isGoogleSignedIn) => {
        if (!this.props.isSignedIn && isGoogleSignedIn){
            await this.props.signIn(this.auth.currentUser.get().getId());
        } else if (this.props.isSignedIn && !isGoogleSignedIn) {
            await this.props.signOut();
        }
    }

    handleSignIn = () => {
        this.auth.signIn();
    }

    handleSignOut = () => {
        this.auth.signOut();
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that the SIGN_IN action (dispatched by calling `this.props.signIn()`) is getting called multiple times when I log in from the '/login' page, and get redirected.

It appears that the redirect occurs before the redux store has properly updated the value of `isSignedIn` and this results in a duplicate SIGN_IN action dispatch.

How can I prevent this? I considered adding a short delay before the redirect, but I'm not sure that's the right way.

EDIT:
I found out that this is happening because I'm rendering the GoogleAuth component twice on the login page (once in the header, and once on the page itself). This resulted in the action getting dispatched twice. Both GoogleAuth components detected the change in authentication status, and as a result both dispatched a SIGN_IN action. There was no delay in propagation of redux store data to the connected component, at least in this scenario.

Comment: Do you return something in the if (!props.isSignedIn) { ... } from the Login component ? if not your Redicrect will be returned resulting in invalid behavior

Comment: @JiaSH Yes, I'm returning the value of a renderHelper function. I've left that code out as it isn't relevant to this issue.

Comment: and where do the props for login come from ? edit : I mean theres no reason that login triggers the redirect if the prop as the store value :)

Comment: Login is a connected component, and has access to the slice of redux store state containing `isSignedIn`. When that value changes to true, the redirect is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out.

I'm rendering the GoogleAuth component twice on the login page - once in the header, and once within the main content. That's why the action was getting dispatched twice.

Both GoogleAuth components detected the change in authentication status, and as a result both dispatched a SIGN_IN action.